# How to make a String of urls in a file using Android so that they can be called back later

Tags: java, android, list

I'm an Android developer and I'm trying to figure out how to call back a certain string in a file so it can be used as a URL in a WebView in another activity. To keep in mind there can be more than one String in a file and let say I want a specific one based on the button I press.

This is my code:

```
    public class LoadArticle extends ActionBarActivity {

MainAct mainStuff;
WebView wv;
Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_article);
   // wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    MainAct mainStuff = this.mainStuff;



    while(mainStuff.listOfUrls.isEmpty()!= true)
    {
        myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("Push Me");

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonLay);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(myButton, lp);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    FileInputStream fileIS = openFileInput("file.txt");
                    int read = -1;
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while((read = fileIS.read()) != -1) {


                        buffer.append((char)read);
                    }

                    String urlWV = buffer.substring(0, buffer.indexOf("<>"));

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoadArticle.this,MainAct.class);
                    //intent.putExtra("theURL", urlWV);
                    startActivity(intent);


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You send it in the bundle (like what you are doing with the line `//intent.putExtra("theURL", urlWV);`) and then get it in the next activity using `getIntent().getStringExtra("theURL");`. Also, look into using final statics (or something more localized at least) for your keys.

Comment: I did, but it didn't work @zgc7009

 `Intent intent = getIntent();
        myURL = intent.getStringExtra("theURL");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.loadUrl(myURL);
        wv.requestFocus();`